# unclear python instance method (increments type() )

Tags: python, python-3.x

in a code example on [this](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php#Static-Methods) site i saw the following code example:

```
class Robot:
    __counter = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        type(self).__counter += 1
        
    def RobotInstances():
        return Robot.__counter
```

The `__init__` method in the example above is incrementing the `__counter` whenever the class is instantiated.

My question is: Since `type(self)` is supposed to return the type of  an object, can it also be assigned to?

Comment: `type(self)` returns the type of `self`. i.e. the class.

Comment: WRT (3), did you try and see?

Comment: __counter in this example is a class variable rather than an instance variable. Are you familiar with the difference?

Comment: `type(self)` will return `Robot`, so you're assigning to `Robot.__counter`. Assigning to `self.__counter` would create an individual instance variable for each instance.

Comment: "since type(self) is supposed to return the type of an object, how can it be the target of an assignment ?" it isn't, this is attribute assignment. Just like any other object, `my_object.some_attribute += 1` increments that attribute on that object (if it exists, otherwise, it throws an Attribute Error). Types/classes are like any other object, they are *instances* of `type`, which is itself a class/type, a *metaclass*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238638/discussion-on-question-by-dror-unclear-python-instance-method-increments-type).

Comment: You're *not* "assigning to the type of an object". You're assigning to the attribute `__counter` of the object returned by `type(self)`. And in this example, `type(self)` is the same as `Robot`.

Comment: "since type(self) is supposed to return the type of an object, can it also be assigned to ?" You can just try that. (Note: It does not work. You cannot assign to a function call.)

Comment: `self` is a `Robot` instance. `type(self)` is *`Robot` itself*. In Python, everything is an object, *including the classes themselves*. That means `Robot` is itself an object, and as such, it has attributes, and as such you can assign to such attributes.